# How to avoid too many empty records?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

- Ember      : 1.5.0-beta.2
- Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7

I have the following router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

My `PostsNewRoute` creates a new record in the `model` hook:

```
App.PostsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('post');
  }
});
```

Since I don't want transient record to be visible, I filter them out in my `PostsRoute`:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.find('post');
    return this.store.filter('post', function(post) {
      return !post.get('isNew');
    });
  }
});
```

This works as expected, but every transition to `posts.new` add a new record to the store, which is something I would like to avoid. So, instead of calling `createRecord` every time the model hook is called, I filter the store for an empty record and return this if there is one found:

```
App.PostsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var route = this;

    return this.store.filter('post', function(post) {
      return post.get('isNew');
    }).then(function(result) {
      return result.get('firstObject') || route.store.createRecord('post');
    );
});
```

This gives me at the most one empty record.

My question: is there a better way to avoid my store being populated with (many) empty records ?

UPDATE:

Instead of filtering on the `isNew` attribute, I can probably use `currentModel`:

```
  model: function() {
    this.get('currentModel') || this.store.createRecord('post');
  };
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something, here, but why not just not create a new record? have the form generate from an object that is not placed in the store?

Comment: I see 2 reasons for using `createRecord`: 1) when I want to validate the form data, I want to call a `validate` method defined on a model and 2) if I have my `submit` action to create an object that added to the store, I still end up with 'empty' records if my `save()` is rejected.

Comment: What if you just trap and destroy the records if the page is left without saving?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this addon https://github.com/dockyard/ember-data-route to clean up when you leave a `/new` route. It hooks into the `willTransition` action hook that gets called on the route whenever a transition occurs.

The source code is a short read: https://github.com/dockyard/ember-data-route/blob/master/addon/mixins/data-route.js.

The alternative would be to not create a new record in the model hook, but according to a comment of yours it doesn't seem to be an option.